# How do I get the name="" attribute value for a different ViewModel's properties?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

- My ASP.NET Core web-application has a login-form on two different pages.
- One page (`Login.cshtml`) is the main login form and uses `LoginViewModel`.
- The other page (`Main.cshtml`) has its own ViewModel type. The `<form>` on the this page will `POST` to the first page, like so:

#### LoginViewModel.cs

```
class LoginViewModel {

    [Required]
    public String UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public String Password { get; set; }
}
```

#### Login.cshtml

```
@model LoginViewModel

<section>

@using( Html.BeginForm() ) {

    <div class="field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor( m => m.UserName )
    @* validation messages, display-names, etc omitted for brevity *@
    </div>

    <div class="field">
    @Html.PasswordFor( m => m.Password )
    </div>
}

</section>
```

#### Main.cshtml

```
@model MainViewModel

<h2>Login</h2>

<form action="@Url( action: "Login" )" method="post">

    <div class="field">
    @Html.TextBoxFor( m => /* What goes here? */ )
    </div>

    <div class="field">
    @Html.PasswordFor( m => /* What goes here? */ )
    </div>

</form>

<h2>Register</h2>

<!-- etc -->
```

I know I can simply hardcode `<input type="text" name="UserName" />` and `<input type="password" name="Password" />` but that introduces maintenance issues if I were to rename `LoginViewModel::UserName`, for example as it becomes a magic-string.

I can't simply add `LoginViewModel` as a member of `MainViewModel` because then `TextBoxFor( m => m.LoginVM.UserName )` will render `name="LoginVM.UserName" which is incorrect.

Comment: Are you wanting to include a 'Login' form in the `Main.cshtml` view (in additional to what the view is displaying)? If so, then you should be using `@Html.Partial()` (or `@Html.Action()` if you need so additional server side logic) to add a partial view of your login form

Comment: But if you want to use `LoginViewModel as a member of MainViewModel`, then the POST method just needs to include `[Bind(Prefix="LoginVM")]LoginViewModel model` to 'strip' the prefix

Comment: @StephenMuecke I specifically do not want to re-use the `Login.cshtml`'s HTML in my `Main.cshtml` page. And I don't want to include `LoginViewModel` inside `MainViewModel` either. I just want a way to safely get the exact same `name=""` attribute value in multiple pages without using hardcoded strings.

Comment: @Html.PasswordFor( m => m.SelectedUserName, Model.UserName, 'html stuff' )

Comment: You need to add another property to your view model call selectedusername.

Comment: Why do you not want to use `Login.cshtml`'s HTML in the main view? If you want to have a Login Form with in the main view then that is exactly what you want in order to post back to your `LogIn()` method (although its not clear why you are not following normal practice and just decorating the main method with `[Authorize]` so you are automatically redirected to the Login page and back again if successful)

Comment: @TheOrangeGoblin That's precisely what I don't want to do because then I ahve to keep the definition of `MainViewModel` in-sync with `LoginViewModel`.

Comment: But if you do want it, then typically you would load a partial of the Login form using ajax (there is no point including the Login form (and a Register form) if they are already logged in)

Comment: @StephenMuecke Because for business reasons the Login form on the login page has different text and content than the login form on the main page. Adding `[Authorize]` is not going to help either.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Using AJAX to load some static HTML in a page that's already server-generated page is just asinine!

Comment: Then just have a separate partial view for the other login form and load it using `@Html.Partial()`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180703/discussion-between-stephen-muecke-and-dai).

Answer (score -1):

Use a view component. Create the file `ViewComponents\LoginViewComponent.cs`. Inside:

```
public class LoginViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    public Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync() =>
        Task.FromResult(View());
}
```

Then, create the view `Views\Shared\Components\Login\Default.cshtml`. Inside, add the login form code. Finally, in both your Login and Main views add the following where you want the form to appear:

```
@await Component.InvokeAsync("Login")
```

Comment: I don't see how this helps my problem because ViewComponents don't support model-binding (even the 1-way model-binding I'm after) nor let you use HTML helper extension methods because no ViewModel object is passed into them ( https://github.com/dsplaisted/strongnamer/issues/23 ) - additionally, I explicitly mentioned in posting that I don't want to use the same HTML for the login form on the Main Form and Login page.

Comment: Don't know where you got that info, but it's all wrong. They're like mini actions. Everything works virtually the same.

Comment: I got it from Microsoft's own documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.1 "View components don't use model binding"

Comment: They're talking about in terms of providing param values, like an action. You very much can use models, tag helpers, etc., and you can have a model declaration in your view just like any other view.

Answer (score -2):

I can sort-of hack-it by using the `nameof()` operator which gives me the same output for trivial properties:

```
<input type="text"     name="@( nameof(LoginViewModel.UserName) )" />
<input type="password" name="@( nameof(LoginViewModel.Password) )" />
```

Comment: Why don't you use partial view for both?

Comment: @Justcode I explained in a comment that the login form on `Login.cshtml` and the login form on `Main.cshtml` have different HTML and content so using the same Partial for both is inappropriate. I do recognize I could have a single dedicated Partial for `Main.cshtml` that does use `LoginViewModel` but it seems like overkill considering I don't need two-way model-binding on `Main.cshtml`, it only needs to POST data to the POST Login action method which will return `Login.cshtml` if there are any errors.

Comment: If you have different requirement lets say you are using username,pwd, and one additional checkbox in the main.cshtml then you can use abstraction to create new model for main.cshtml.